# Jump to current executable line in Android Studio debugger

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging

I'm stepping through code in the Android Studio debugger. I'm viewing some arbitrary line. Now I want to get back to the current executable line. In Visual Studio I would use `Alt-Num-*`. Is there a way or shortcut key in Android Studio for this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Run->Show Execution Point or Alt+F10